# JavaScript- Add Selected Option into a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm attempting to have a combo box be populated by a option the user selects. Once the user selects the item and clicks Add, I want to add the text value of the selected item into a list.

I have the first part working as I'd like, however, I'm having a rough time with Adding the values into the list. I honestly have no idea how to accomplish it or what would be the best way? If someone could just send me along the right path of what I need to look into and what sort of event listeners, methods, I should look at would be great. I'm super new to JavaScript and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

What I have so far:

```js
  function changeOptions(link) {
   if (link=="") {
  return; }
  
  switch(link) {
  case "Category1":
   var inventory=new Array (
     "Item1",
     "Item2",
     "Item3");
   break;
  case "Category2":
   var inventory=new Array (
     "Item4",
     "Item5",
     "Item6");
     break;
 } 

    
   i = document.form.items.options.length;
  if (i > 0) {
    document.form.items.options.length -= i; document.form.items.options[i] = null;
  }

   for (i=0; i< inventory.length; i++) {  
   
  document.form.items.options[i] = new Option(); 
  document.form.items.options[i].text = inventory[i];
  document.form.items.options[i].value = inventory[i];
    }
 }
```

```html
<form name=form >
    <b>Select a Category</b><br />
    <a onclick="changeOptions('Category1')">Category1</a> | 
    <a onclick="changeOptions('Category2')">Category2</a> 
    <br /><br/>
    <b>Inventory</b><br/>
    <select name="items" multiple="multiple" style="height:150px;width:400px;">
    <option value="">Select An Item</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name= "add" value="Add">
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some code to append the selected value to a list beneath your combo box. I added a form event listener for submit. On submit we get the value of the select box and add it to a list. You can tweak this and add validation and stuff. I also added some id's to the html to query the elements with in the JS.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var list = document.getElementById('list');

var addItem = function(item) {
  return '<li>' + item + '</li>';
}

var handleSubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  list.innerHTML += addItem(select.value);
}

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);

function changeOptions(link) {
  if (link == "") {
    return;
  }

  switch (link) {
    case "Category1":
      var inventory = new Array(
        "Item1",
        "Item2",
        "Item3");
      break;
    case "Category2":
      var inventory = new Array(
        "Item4",
        "Item5",
        "Item6");
      break;
  }


  i = document.form.items.options.length;
  if (i > 0) {
    document.form.items.options.length -= i;
    document.form.items.options[i] = null;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {

    document.form.items.options[i] = new Option();
    document.form.items.options[i].text = inventory[i];
    document.form.items.options[i].value = inventory[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form" name=form>
  <b>Select a Category</b>
  <br />
  <a onclick="changeOptions('Category1')">Category1</a> |
  <a onclick="changeOptions('Category2')">Category2</a> 
  <br />
  <br/>
  <b>Inventory</b>
  <br/>
  <select id="select" name="items" multiple="multiple" style="height:150px;width:400px;">
    <option value="">Select An Item</option>
  </select>
  <input id="btn" type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
</form>
<ul id="list">

</ul>
```